# SMS starts with "ACTA" sent without my consent

Tags: sms, spam

On 26-Feb-2020 at 4.24 PM IST, an unknown SMS has been sent from my Redmi 7A Android phone without my consent to a completely unknown number. It starts with "ACTA" and then contains some encoded data. It's all either encrypted or garbage. I have no clue what this is and I can not infer anything from this.

> [image]

All apps before installation are scanned by a built-in security check. I have run a security scan on my phone and nothing suspicious was found except needing to update MIUI.  No app was installed on that day and I do not download any unknown apk's from unknown sites. All apps have always been installed from Google Play Store.

The number does not exist in my contact list and has never ever been dialed from or any call received on this phone. TrueCaller site reports that number as a spam number from India.

Could someone explain this?

Comment: Possibly some kind of account login verification.

Comment: It could be [Smsc number](https://tricksbaba.com/sms-center-number/) of your carrier. Check in your SMS app settings to see Smsc number

Comment: Are you using [iMobile by ICICI Bank](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.csam.icici.bank.imobile)? Found [a forum thread](https://in.c.mi.com/thread-1721322-1-0.html?sources=1) mentioning about sending "ACTA" SMS. [Another article](https://vms.drweb.com/virus/?i=14983943) is about an SMS sender malware, though it's really unclear what it is from.

Comment: First of all thank you all for your inputs. This helped me to start looking in right direction. I first called my carrier and they informed me that the number does not belong to them. I have 2 different banking applications that allow me to access my bank account details thru respective apps. I then called ICICI Bank customer care and the representative has confirmed that this number belongs to their iMobile servers and the message is some kind of legit verification message required by the app to function properly. To be continued...

Comment: Earlier I must have clicked 'Allow this app to send SMS' so the whole process happened automatically. I am relived that there's no spam or some kind of hacking attempt. @Andrew T, you may like to formulate an answer and I will accept it. Thank you all for your inputs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to quick research, **the "ACTA" SMS is used by ICICI Bank for a verification/activation message on their mobile apps (e.g. [iMobile](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.csam.icici.bank.imobile))**.

From [Mi Community - Unable to activate icici i-mobile app on my POCOFONE F1](https://in.c.mi.com/thread-1721322-1-0.html?sources=1),

> Post #10
>
> Solved after the solution given by the online imobile team.
> During the activation process,  **you get some random text message (ACTA *** which need to be sent for verification) , you copy the entire text and send the same to 9215676766 instead of +91222208888 (icici server number which is usually busy)**.
> This sms need to be sent within 90 seconds and jump back to imobile app and proceed with the activation by setting 4 digit pin and grid value verification. [...]
>
> <sup>(Emphasis added)</sup>

Also, thanks to the [OP's confirmation on the comment thread](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/221639/sms-sent-without-my-consent-from-my-redmi-7a-phone/221667#comment286953_221639),

> I then called ICICI Bank customer care and the representative has confirmed that this number (*ed. +9184220...*) belongs to their iMobile servers and the message is some kind of legit verification message required by the app to function properly. Earlier I must have clicked 'Allow this app to send SMS' so the whole process happened automatically.